# Have components Save button trigger action on different component in Angular?

Tags: angular, primeng

I have an angular component using an NGPrime datatable.... When a user selects a row they get a popup component that lets them edit the data.... after they edit the data they can click 'save' button. How can I send that save button click action to the component with the datatable so I can trigger a refresh of the data?

Comment: Could you please provide a code sample? It's hard to reason about potential solutions without knowing how your components are structured. If edit popup is used only in that component, maybe simply use an `Output()`?

Comment: I'm not sure how to even start.... basically what I'm wanting to do is have an action occur in a component when a button is clicked in another component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several ways for this.

If they are unrelated components then

**Generic Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable()
export class ShareService  {   
  constructor() { } 
  private paramSource = new BehaviorSubject("");
  sharedData = this.paramSource.asObservable();
  setParam(param:string) { this.paramSource.next(param)}    
}
```

put in providers in appmodule

```
providers:[ShareService ]
```

put in constructors in components

```
constructor(private shareService: ShareService  ){}
```

from first component send like

```
this.shareService.setParam('Sending param');
```

from second component receive like

```
 this.shareService.sharedData.subscribe(data=> { console.log(data); })
```

**Routing Method**

you can put parameter in router and send it. You can make router as parametric like your routing.ts

```
{ path: 'component/:param', component: RelatedComponent },
```

then in component you want to get it call like import `ActiveRoute` in constructor

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}
```

and get like

```
this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('param')
```

or if you dont want to show param in route you can send as state like below code

```
this.router.navigate(['your_component_url'], {state: { param: 'data you send' } });
```

to read state in constructor `this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.param;`

**Storage Method**

you can set to localStorage or sessionStorage then take from storage from another component.

```
localStorage.setItem("param","parameter")

localStorage.getItem("param")
```

If they are parent child components then  you can do above too and also much prefable to use

**@Input method**

```
<your_child_component param="{{ parameter}}"></your_child_component>
```

in child component getlike

```
@Input param;
```

Answer (score 0):

Establish a common link between components  using service.

Assume when user clicks on your component popup from there you should pass an event emitter which will be listened in the table component. So table component can provide the reload of table.